# What is the 108 word in the Tanakh

Tags: number, tanach

What is the 108 word in Genesis? I have tried to count the Hebrew text but I'm not sure. My name Lynette according to the aleph bet  totals a sum of 108. I am trying to find the 108 word in Genesis so that I can see what the word is

Comment: I am not making this an answer because I am not sure if I am right, but I came up with "hamayim" (the water) in Gen 1:10.

Comment: Migrate to BH ?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's on-topic here afaict.

Comment: Just so you know, the only way I can think of that "Lynette" comes to 108 is if the "tt" is transliterated "טט". But that's not how it'd be transliterated in Hebrew -- Hebrew doesn't use doubled letters the way English does. (That said, another language written in Hebrew characters may.)

Comment: Do you not have a Hebrew name?

Comment: @CashCow Presumably this is her Hebrew name.

Comment: @CashCow, many Jews don't. In fact, many Jews born to religious parents don't, especially girls/women.

Answer (score 2):

It's ולמקוה, *ulmikve*, "and to the collection of", in verse 10. Source: my local copy.

---

(This counts words connected by a maqaf as two words, as usual.)

Comment: Did you count by hand?

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes.